# Grouping by Loan Count of 50

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will capture a count of 0 AND 50 to form Group 1 of loans, a count of 51 and 100 to count Group 2 of loans ect.. I am trying to count in 50 increments loans per say a bank and group them in counts of 50.  I would need all loan numbers listed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DLR_NAME, 
    ACCOUNT, 
    COUNT(*) AS GROUPCOUNT, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT BETWEEN 1 AND 50 Then 'Group 1'
         WHEN COUNT BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 'Group 2'
```

Something like this.  I am a novice at this currently.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: What would the output of a group of 0 look like?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but try this:

```
declare @GroupSize decimal = 50.0
select BankID,
    LoanID,
    floor((_row - 1) / @GroupSize) as [GroupNum]
from (
    select BankID, 
        LoanID,
        row_number() over (partition by BankID order by BankID, LoanID) as _row
    from Loan
) a
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4092/14)

Comment: Might want to add `+ 1` to your `GroupNum` logic to skip group 0 (so rows 1-50 are 1 instead of 0).  Cool solution, though!

Comment: The `floor()` would be unnecessary if `@groupsize` were an integer, and the `BankId` in the `order by` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you actually need, but maybe something like this?

```
select
    DLR_NAME,
    ACCOUNT,
    CASE WHEN GROUPCOUNT BETWEEN 1 AND 50 Then 'Group 1'
         WHEN GROUPCOUNT BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 'Group 2'
    END
from
(
    select,
        DLR_NAME, 
        ACCOUNT,
        COUNT(*) AS GROUPCOUNT
    from
        account
    group by
        DLR_NAME, 
        ACCOUNT
) X
```

This will calculate how many rows each DLR_NAME + ACCOUNT has in table account and then assign the group name based on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DLR_NAME, ACCOUNT , 'Group ' + Convert(varchar(10), (Convert(int, GROUPCOUNT / 50) + 1)) as Group From
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DLR_NAME, 
    ACCOUNT, 
    COUNT(*) AS GROUPCOUNT
From Account 
Group by DLR_NAME, ACCOUNT
)T
```

**Explanation :**

```
Convert(varchar(10), (Convert(int, GROUPCOUNT / 50) + 1))

GROUPCOUNT = 57 then 
1). Convert(varchar(10), (Convert(int, 57 / 50) + 1)) 
2). Convert(varchar(10), (Convert(int, 1.14) + 1)) 
3). Convert(varchar(10), (1 + 1)) 
4). 2 as Varchar
```

No need to manage case when for that case.

Comment: can you add some explanation?